# Which is greater, |$\vec a + \vec b$| or |$\vec a$|+|$\vec b$|?

Tags: vectors, geometry

Pardon me if this has been asked before, I have encountered this question and its many variations in many physics mock papers.
I want to know if there is some sort of way to logically attempt these types of questions, I am not in requirement of an answer but a method which will help in solving questions of this form...

Comment: This should be asked in http://math.stackechange.com. It's an extremely important question on which a lot of modern mathematics rides.

Comment: I found in a physics test paper online :/

Comment: That doesn't mean it's not a math question. Trust me. You will get the "full download" over there. There are entire mathematical fields like functional analysis which live and die by this very question. Flag this to be moved to the math folks and you will get much better answers.

Comment: So a mod will do it or I should delete my question?

Comment: A moderator will move it for you, if they feel it's appropriate. Just so you know, I think it's a good question and I up-voted it, it's just not physics, per se, but much more fundamental than that (even though we use it a lot in physics, too).

Comment: [Triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality)

Comment: As @AccidentalFourierTransform mentioned, it's the triangle equation. With $\vec c:=-(\vec a +\vec b)$ you have a triangle.

Comment: I think this is a valid physics question. There's nothing wrong with it. A lot of physics also rides on this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  |\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}|^{2} &=
  (\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}) \cdot (\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}) \\
  &= \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{a}+\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b}+
     \mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{b} \\
  &= |\mathbf{a}|^{2}+2\, \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b}+|\mathbf{b}|^{2} \\
  & \leq |\mathbf{a}|^{2}+2|\mathbf{a}||\mathbf{b}|+|\mathbf{b}|^{2}
         \quad (\because \: \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} \leq
         |\mathbf{a}||\mathbf{b}|) \\
  & = (|\mathbf{a}|+|\mathbf{b}|)^{2} \\
  \therefore \quad   |\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}|
  & \leq |\mathbf{a}|+|\mathbf{b}|
         \quad (\because \: |\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}|, |\mathbf{a}|,
         |\mathbf{b}| \geq 0)
\end{align*}

Comment: true as far as it goes, but the hard part is $|a||b| \ge a.b$ i.e. the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality

Comment: For vectors in "normal" 3 dimensional space you can have a fairly easy proof that $|a| |b| \ge a.b$ since $a.b = |a||b| cos(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors. Since $cos(\theta) \le 1$ the result follows.

Comment: I don't quite get the fourth step, how was the equality sign changed to "<=" ?

Comment: By definition $\mathbf{a \cdot b}=ab\cos \theta$ and $-1\leq \cos \theta \leq 1$

Answer (score -1):

|a|+|b| will have to be greater than or equal to |a+b| and we can see that without any math just using pure logic.
When you do a + b, b can do 2 things compliment a or destruct its value. Even in general math if a is positive and b is negative or vice versa, b would negate a, but on the contrary when you apply a || function first and then add, you are assuring that b always compliments a.
Hope it helps

Comment: I agree with CuriosOne , if you want a detailed proof go to the math section, but the above solution is my interpretation of it